# NSNumberFormatter for Different region

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I will receive $5.00 for US, ¥5.00 for Japan, 5.00€ for Europe, etc. But I don't want that. 
I want to get the same thing in every locale: $5.00 for US, $5.00 for Japan, $5.00 for Europe.
Here is what I have tried:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSNumber *tmp = (NSNumber *)[NSString notNullString:[details objectForKey:@"askingPricePerCarat"]];
NSString *numberAsString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[tmp doubleValue]]];
askingPricePerCarat = numberAsString;
```

Comment: It's a bit misleading showing $ for every country. I do believe apple have a rule that says currency has to be shown local to the area so if you are in Japan it has to be shown in Yen ¥ and in Europe it has to be shown in Euros € so I don't think Apple will allow this through. I will look for the ruling.

Comment: yeah i understand this,but is there anyway for this ?

Comment: Well what's the point if it isn't allowed? Yes it can be done but there is no point so why waste your time trying or ours?

Comment: [numberFormatter setLocale:self.priceLocale]; is this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the answer of this question, is based on the device's Region Format settings, not the language. If the region is set to United States you will get en_US regardless of which language you're using

```
 NSNumberFormatter * fmt;
 NSNumber          * n;

 fmt = [ [ NSNumberFormatter alloc ] init ];
 n   = [ NSNumber numberWithFloat: 10 ];

 [ fmt setFormatterBehavior: NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4 ];
 [ fmt setCurrencySymbol: @"$" ];
 [ fmt setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle ];

 // NSLog( @"%@", [ fmt stringFromNumber: n ];

[ fmt release ];
```

use

```
Currency.text = [ fmt stringFromNumber: n ];
```

Comment: So yes. Customize the formatter. But en_US is not a region. It's a locale identifier. The country portion defines most of the  format options. You can ignore popeye's comments.

Comment: Yeah above this code helps me when i change any region like japan,china now i set to Dollor and this works me Fine