# ios8 currency Symobol has Country Code in front

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8

I am trying to get a currency symbol from the locale, but seems in IOS8 the currencySymbol returned is US$ instead of $. anyone knows what changed?

Thanks,

```
NSLocale *lcl = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSNumberFormatter *fmtr = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[fmtr setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[fmtr setLocale:lcl];

NSLog( @"%@", [fmtr internationalCurrencySymbol] );
NSLog( @"%@", [fmtr currencySymbol] );
```

2014-12-30 00:11:35.617[1344:424347] USD
2014-12-30 00:11:35.617[1344:424347] US$

Comment: what's your locale? `NSLog("%@", [[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier]);`

Comment: That's probably because US dollars are not the only kind of dollars.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set in $ instead of US$ then you can refer my answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25860427/3800154)

```
NSNumberFormatter * fmt;
NSNumber          * n;

fmt = [ [ NSNumberFormatter alloc ] init ];
n   = [ NSNumber numberWithFloat: 10 ];

[ fmt setFormatterBehavior: NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4 ];
[ fmt setCurrencySymbol: @"$" ];
[ fmt setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle ];

// NSLog( @"%@", [ fmt stringFromNumber: n ];

[ fmt release ];
```

now use

```
Currency.text = [ fmt stringFromNumber: n ];
```

Comment: but I don`t want to hardcoded the currency symbol. Seems in IOS7, I got $ but in ios8 i got US$